# How to fix the position of an element outside the flow of the page in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to have an image sit on top of the flow of the page, fixed relative to the viewport.  Here's what I've got.  `<Post>` is a custom component composed of a hierarchy of other custom components ending in text and image components.

```
<View>
    <Text>Header bar</Text>
    <ScrollView>
        {records.map((record, index) => {
            return <Post key={index} post={record} handleVisibilty={handleModalVisibilty} />
        })}
        <Modal ....>
            ....
        </Modal>
    </ScrollView>
<View>
```

Here's my image component:

```
<TouchableHighlight>
    <Image source={require('../assets/myImage.png')} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

If I place the touchablehighlight inside of the scrollview, it takes up space that the scrollview could (and should) use.  That's when I set its display to `relative`.  When I set it to `absolute` with `top: 0`, for example, it just disappears from the page altogether. I want my image to sit towards the bottom right corner of the page, with the content scrolling beneath it while it stays fixed.

Comment: I didn't clearly understand.if you want to stick an item on top of scrollview you could use "stickyHeaderIndices" prop of scrollview.
 but if you want to position it absolute outside of scroll, you could use an View outside of scrollview and both View & scrollview wrapped with fragment

Comment: Thanks @LordPooria, that's what I ended up doing as I couldn't get a FlatList working as shown in the answer below.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. tnx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use FlatList instead of Scrolview. For example

```
const DATA = [
    {title: 'text'},{title: 'text'}, ...
]
```

Then use the FlatList.

```
<View>
    <Text>Header bar</Text>
    <TouchableHighlight>
        <Image source={require('../assets/myImage.png')} />
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <FlatList 
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Text> {item.title} </Text>}
        ...
    />
<View>
```

Comment: I've edited my question to give a better indication of the complexity inside my scrollview.  I'm not sure how to incorporate the `data` property with this composition.

Comment: I think, You can use Modal outside of the scrollview.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the arrow.  Here's how my renderItem looks: `renderItem={{item} => <Post post={item} handleVisibilty={handleModalVisibilty} />}`

Comment: It was just lack of brackets around `{item}`. Unfortunately I can't get it to render my items with my above code.

Comment: I edited the code for renderItem. Please try again?

Comment: Did you only add the brackets? I've already done that.  It outputs no items with my `records` array as the `data`.